# Align circles in diagonal corners

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I was wondering if there was any way of aligning circles in diagonal corners like in my first picture down below. Now I know there is a round corner effect and I also have a script that rounds only specific corners that I want, but I've been puzzled when I see people have an actual circle guide perfectly placed in the odd corner. I've seen it plenty of times on Dribbble snapshots.

[image]

Comment: That's not how it works. You make a guide to create a shape, not add the guide later. That't why it fits perfectly, because it was there to help create the shape.

Comment: what do you need  exactly? to round your shape perfectly? or just to place circles to the corners?

Comment: Yeah okay,I understand what you're trying to say. Here's the thing:
The questioner is talking about this: ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QMYxI.png) Correct me if I'm wrong, he's trying to find out how to make that circular guide. The design up here is mine, and how I did is shaping every corner manually using a shape combined with other shape (pathfinder stuff). For example, the top left corner, is a result of a rectangle intersected with a ellipse (or circle). This will guarantee you to achieve that 100% smooth corner, I don't recommend you to use any script :p **Rem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I understand what you want

Using the free tool from Astute Graphics called [SubScribe](http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/subscribe/)

one of those great tools is to draw a circle ... ( and nothing except circle) between a given two tangents as follow.

First long press the tool `Circle by 2 or 3 points` [image] a flyout will appear as follow

[image]

select `Tangent Circle` and select any two sides.

[image]

and click

[image]

that's it

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is **exactly** what I was talking about. Thank you so much! <3