# Aligning circles to non-90-degree corners

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I am trying to achieve perfect circular corners for some shapes. This seems really easy for 90° angles, but for more complicated corners, I can't seem to figure out how to get the circle to align perfectly with the lines.

I have found [solutions by using Astute Graphics SubScribe](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48642/align-circles-in-diagonal-corners), but I cannot afford that at the moment, and would assume that this would be possible in Vanilla AI.

[image: Image of what I want to achieve with circular corners.]

Comment: You *might* want to look at VectorScribe rather than SubScribe at astute. The rounded corner feature which is part of VectorScribe would easily round the corners of the C without the need to align a circle and do it manually. (There are free trials of their stuff which may help for a project or two currently).

Comment: @Scott there might be other reasons to align a circle than rounding a corner IMHO. We dont know. Offsetting is easy enough. (plugins can also be problematic in environments where you need to keep changing the computer all the time, like for me i use about 15 different computers each day)

Comment: @joojaa Astute plugins do *not* require them to be installed to open/further edit art created by using their plug ins.

Comment: @Scott yeah but they still need to be present to be used in any new workflow. Which is why at work i only use functions in vanilla AI no matter what i do because then same workflow works on all computers. Im just pointing out that its purposefull to work plugin free in some cases. But for me offsetting serves using other even more limited applications. I mean sometimes you even need to bisect, horror

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you can  not use the round corners feature? all you need to do is select the corner with the white arrow tool and drag the blue dot (or type the value in toolbar).

More info [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/88227/how-to-make-corners-round-in-illustrator)

But yeah you can do this with offsetting by the radius of your circle see [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/104393/18306)

**PS** while this seems like a link only answer its not ive described how to do this also im linking inside stack exchange which should not link rot,

Comment: Yes - I am aware of the AI default rounding tool and it would work in 99% of my use cases, but for this one, I need to use a circle to round for illustrative purposes. Using Offset solves my issue. I can't believe I hadn't thought of that. Thank you so much.